# I'm unable to view Eureka dashboard

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

When I access http://localhost:8761/ or http://localhost:8761/eureka I get "Whitelabel Error Page".

My app class:

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableEurekaServer
    public class DiscoveryServerApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

application.properties:

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
server.port=8761
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/templates/
spring.freemarker.prefer-file-system-access=false
```

pom.xml from discovery server module:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

pom.xml from parent project:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<modules>
    <module>inventory-service</module>
    <module>order-service</module>
    <module>product-service</module>
    <module>discovery-server</module>
</modules>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Discovery server application logs:

```java
    2023-09-12T14:25:01.469-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [           main] c.y.g.d.DiscoveryServerApplication       : Starting DiscoveryServerApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 28640
    2023-09-12T14:25:01.472-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [           main] c.y.g.d.DiscoveryServerApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
    2023-09-12T14:25:02.662-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
    2023-09-12T14:25:02.672-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2023-09-12T14:25:02.672-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.12]
    2023-09-12T14:25:02.777-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2023-09-12T14:25:02.778-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1259 ms
    2023-09-12T14:25:03.563-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
    2023-09-12T14:25:03.624-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http) with context path ''
    2023-09-12T14:25:03.637-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [           main] c.y.g.d.DiscoveryServerApplication       : Started DiscoveryServerApplication in 2.794 seconds (process running for 3.526)
    2023-09-12T14:25:03.942-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [2)-192.168.15.7] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    2023-09-12T14:25:03.943-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [2)-192.168.15.7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    2023-09-12T14:25:03.944-03:00  INFO 28640 --- [2)-192.168.15.7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm using Spring Boot 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on `spring-cloud.version`. I changed it to `<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>` and the discovery server worked.